# iOS 3.2+: set a customized UISlider back to default images?

Tags: ios, uislider

I have a UISlider with a customized appearance (via setThumbImage, etc.).
At some point in my application, I need to be able to reset the UISlider's look back to the default images.

I tried setting all images to nil, but that just made the slider disappear altogether:

```
[slider setThumbImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setMinimumTrackImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setMaximumTrackImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have over rided the default images, you have to recreate the slider or have default images separately and then add it.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping it wouldn't come to this, as I've layed out the GUI in Interface Builder, and I'm not quite sure how I'll go about taking those sliders out and replacing them with new ones while keeping the IBAction connections intact (I'm still a beginner), but I'll figure it out.